# MYSQL UPDATE with IN and Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery, sql-view

Hi i have tables like this :

table entry :

id  |  total_comments
_____________________
1   |    0
2   |    0
3   |    0
4   |    0

table comments :

id  |  eid  | comment
_____________________
1   |    1   | comment sdfd 
2   |    1   | testing testing  
3   |    1   | comment text 
4   |    2   | dummy comment 
5   |    2   | sample comment 
6   |    1   | fg fgh dfh

Query i write :

```
UPDATE entry 
   SET total_comments = total_comments + 1 
 WHERE id IN ( SELECT eid 
                 FROM comments 
                WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

**Results i get is :**

table entry :

id  |  total_comments
_____________________
1   |    1
2   |    1
3   |    0
4   |    0

**Expected results :**

table entry :

id  |  total_comments
_____________________
1   |    4
2   |    2
3   |    0
4   |    0

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE entry 
   SET total_comments = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                           FROM COMMENTS c
                          WHERE c.eid = id
                       GROUP BY c.eid)
 WHERE id IN ( SELECT eid 
                 FROM comments 
                WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Comment: yeah i am looking for something like that... my motive is to run update query based on subquery.... its to update "total_comments" in "entry" table with acutal number of comments, for id in "entry"

if i run query that i have specified it only adds 1 for all number of comments found in subqery . Here what sql query turns into after subquery runs:

UPDATE entry 
   SET total_comments = total_comments + 1 
 WHERE id IN (1,1,1,2,2,1)

so update runs only once for 1 and 2 id's in entry table. Coz its how IN works. But i want some how to run it 4 times for 1 and 2 times for 2.

Comment: The only way i think is to to run subquery something like that what i dont know how to do:

UPDATE entry 
   SET total_comments = total_comments + @count 
 WHERE id IN ( SELECT eid, count(*) as @count
                 FROM comments 
                WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6))

but then In doesnt work coz of multiple rows and also i dont know how to refer @count in set condition :(

Answer (score 3):

If you really need total_comments in a separate table, I would make that a VIEW.

```
CREATE VIEW entry AS 
  SELECT id, COUNT(comments) AS total_comment 
  FROM comments 
  GROUP BY id
```

This way you avoid the maintenance task of updating the total_comments table altogether.

Comment: +1: I completely agree, this is a better design choice than the current table structure.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what I'd expect. The id is IN the set you give it, so total_comments = total_comments + 1.

It's not going to add one for each instance of the same value: that's not how IN works. IN will return a simple boolean yes/no.

Comment: i know... but i want some method so that i can count number of entry.id in subqery. 

I can do it by running subquery sperate and then running update query using for loop for all those. But i wanna do it in one query thats my porblem :(

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UPDATE entry
  SET total_comments = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM comments
                        WHERE entry.id = comments.eid
                        GROUP BY id)
```

Comment: this will run for all records in entry table but i want to run for only specified records thats why i used IN clause...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE entry e 
    SET total_comments = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE eid = e.id)  
    WHERE 
    e.id in (SELECT eid FROM comments WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6))
```